# Is there a way to create postgres database before it executes changesets in liquibase

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I am using liquibase in my spring boot app and I'm looking for a way to create a database before it executes the changesets.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide more information about your problem, like all the code you've tried for example. That way, more people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually creating a database is one thing that Liquibase cannot do. It expects that the database you want to manage has already been created. Depending on the database platform you are using, it might be possible to connect to the same server that you want to create the database on and then issue SQL commands to create a new database, but that is one area where database servers differ greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database driver you're using, you might be able to create if it doesn't exist.

For instance, if you're using jdbc, you may add `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` in your database url to make it create the database if it doesn't exist.

Full URL :

```
jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/databaseName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```